# Error when switching from gradle osgi plugin to org.dm.bundle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, osgi, bundle

in quartz-sample-nested-jars example:

https://github.com/paulvi/osgi-run/tree/master/osgi-run-test/quartz-sample-nested-jars

there's error, so resulted bundle is not ACTIVE in felix, and can't be started.

Why does the bundle need osgi.wiring.package=commonj.work? Where this comes from? If it were a Gradle dependency of your project, osgi-run would have added it to the runtime... maybe you just need to add a osgiRuntime 'org:commonj.work:version' declaration in the Gradle deps?

full log

```
# parseClassFile(): path=org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.class resource=:file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_74/jre/lib/rt.j
ar!/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.class:
:quartz-sample-nested-jars:createOsgiRuntime
> Building 83% > :quartz-sample-nested-jars:runOsgi

:quartz-sample-nested-jars:runOsgi
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.athaydes.gradle.osgi.quartz-sample-nested-jars [6](R 6.0): mis
sing requirement [com.athaydes.gradle.osgi.quartz-sample-nested-jars [6](R 6.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.packa
ge=commonj.work) Unresolved requirements: [[com.athaydes.gradle.osgi.quartz-sample-nested-jars [6](R 6.0)] osgi.wiring.p
ackage; (osgi.wiring.package=commonj.work)]
ERROR: Bundle com.athaydes.gradle.osgi.quartz-sample-nested-jars [6] Error starting file:/D:/Workspaces/GitHub/osgi-run/
osgi-run-test/quartz-sample-nested-jars/build/osgi/bundle/quartz-sample-nested-jars-1.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleEx
ception: Unable to resolve com.athaydes.gradle.osgi.quartz-sample-nested-jars [6](R 6.0): missing requirement [com.athay
des.gradle.osgi.quartz-sample-nested-jars [6](R 6.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=commonj.work) Unresolved
 requirements: [[com.athaydes.gradle.osgi.quartz-sample-nested-jars [6](R 6.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.packag
e=commonj.work)])
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1371)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
____________________________
Welcome to Apache Felix Gogo

> Building 83% > :quartz-sample-nested-jars:runOsgilb
g! g! g! START LEVEL 1
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (5.4.0)|5.4.0
    1|Active     |    1|c3p0 (0.9.1.1)|0.9.1.1
    2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.16.0)|0.16.0
    3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.16.2)|0.16.2
    4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.12.0)|0.12.0
    5|Active     |    1|quartz (2.2.1)|2.2.1
    6|Installed  |    1|com.athaydes.gradle.osgi.quartz-sample-nested-jars (1.0.0)|1.0.0
    7|Active     |    1|slf4j-api (1.6.6)|1.6.6
    8|Resolved   |    1|slf4j-simple (1.6.6)|1.6.6
> Building 83% > :quartz-sample-nested-jars:runOsgistart 6
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.athaydes.gradle.osgi.quartz-sample-nested-jars [6](R 6.0): mis
sing requirement [com.athaydes.gradle.osgi.quartz-sample-nested-jars [6](R 6.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.packa
ge=commonj.work) Unresolved requirements: [[com.athaydes.gradle.osgi.quartz-sample-nested-jars [6](R 6.0)] osgi.wiring.p
ackage; (osgi.wiring.package=commonj.work)]
> Building 83% > :quartz-sample-nested-jars:runOsgi
```

open issue https://github.com/renatoathaydes/osgi-run/issues/36 (not really belongs there)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the quartz bundle's manifest, which contains this in the `Export-Package` instruction:

```
org.quartz.commonj;
uses:="commonj.work,javax.naming,org.quartz.spi,org.slf4j";
version="2.2.1"
```

And later, in the `Import-Package` instruction, this:

```
commonj.work;resolution:=optional
```

So, in order for this bundle to export `org.quartz.commonj`, it needs to have `commonj.work` imported, but this is a optional import...

I am not sure what the OSGi specification says it should happen in this case, I tried to find out in the Specification but I just couldn't find anything specific to this case... My interpretation is that the bundle should still export the `org.quartz.commonj` package because the specification only says that `optional` requirements must not prevent a bundle's wiring from being satisfied, it does not say anything about exported packages which rely on optional imports, as far as I can tell.

The question now is why this works with the `osgi` plugin, which just calls `Bnd` to create the manifest, but not with `org.dm.bundle`, which also calls `Bnd`, but to create the whole jar...

When running in Felix, I can see that the `org.quartz.commonj` package is successfully exported by the quartz bundle and is made available for wiring to other bundles, so I think this should be allowed to work.

I suggest filling a bug with `org.dm.bundle` or directly with Bnd. I am sure they will be able to give a more solid answer and, if they see it as appropriate, fix any bugs they may have that might be causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not being an OSGI export, I can't say for sure but I suspect that the package "commonj.work" should not be here https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/quartz/pom.xml#L232